# Is there any code-collapse-plugin of vim like this?

Tags: vim

[image]
When I click the plus sign, the code would automatically collapse.

Is there any plugin like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [folding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html). Essentially all you need to get started is:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldcolumn=<n>     " the number of columns to use for folding display at the left
```

and to manipulate it with the mouse, `set mouse=a` to turn on mouse stuff. The `+` and `-` to open/close folds appear in the foldcolumn at the left, next to the line numbers, not directly by the code as you've drawn, but it ought to be good enough! You'll probably want a column width of at least a couple, so you can see folds beyond the first level.

This does depend on folding having been defined for the syntax of the filetype you're currently editing. Vim comes with folding rules for some common things like C, but not everything. It's possible that if it's not shipped with vim, someone's created it, and you could find something suiting you out there.

Comment: @Jichao : From Vim, you should try `:help folding` it is quite long but it provides a complete description of what are folding related commands in Vim, and how to use them.

Comment: @Xavier T.: Yes, the help document of vim is clearer than most of other software. Actually, I have read a lot of them, but did not manage to remeber them. Anyway, I'll try to use the help system before I post a question. ^_^

Comment: @Xavier: The link in the first line is the online copy of `:help folding`, of course. @Jichao sometimes it can be hard to know what keyword to try in the help; no worries!

Answer (score 2):

Setting `foldcolumn` to a number greater than 0 will put a `+` at the beginning of the line that you can click to fold or unfold blocks.