# How to folding php/html in gvim under Windows?

Tags: php, html, vim, editor

This question is based on this question [Is there any code-collapse-plugin of vim like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710104/is-there-any-code-collapse-plugin-of-vim-like-this).

However, I could not find a folding file to get the folding effect I needed.

Could you give a practical method (better you have get the effect with the method) to get php/html's folding effect, even for the xhtml inside a php file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/114138) or [that](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding) will be helpful?